# How to validate boolean values from HTML5 to vmWare Orchestrator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, validation, vmware, erb

I'm presenting a vmWare Orchestrator workflow on a website using Ruby and HTML5. 
When I run the workflow inside Orchestrator it validates and runs the workflow.

When the workflow is presented on my website I receive 400 code validation errors when submitting the form.

Here's what's being submitted to Orchestrator when the checkbox is unchecked, which is incorrect because it is grabbing the value from the previous form field:

`{"scope":"local","name":"exampleServer","type":"string","value":{"string":{"value":"ncc16439"}},"updated":true},{"scope":"local","name":"ConfigureLVM","type":"boolean","value":{"boolean":   {"value":"ncc16439"}},"updated":true}`

ERB:
`<input type="checkbox" id="<%= array['id'] %>" name="<%= array['id'] %>" />`

Inside the input above I've tried setting `value=true, value=false` (for Orchestrator) and using `checked` (for HTML5).

I've hardcoded every option with no success. I believe it is an issue with Orchestrator wanting a T/F value for booleans, where HTML5 accepts on/off when using checked. I haven't been able to find anyone else with this issue.